# why eclipse can run latest change without maven package and copy the ear to wildfly

Tags: java, eclipse

My eclipse has just one jboss runtime and is point to C:\wildfly-23.0.2.Final, when I start the wildfly in eclipse and then change the code in System.out.println, I see the wildfly status change from 'Debugging, Republish' to 'Debugging, Synchronized', and i see my changed code is really run (the System.out.println content is changed in console), but when I check the 'C:\wildfly-23.0.2.Final\standalone\deployments' folder, the ear.deployed file is still the old one, and I even have not run maven > package, so the ear file in workspace target folder is also the old one, then

1. why my new code can really run in debug mode?
2. is it possible that when I change the code, it will automatically build (package) the new code to workspace target folder ear and auto deploy to 'C:\wildfly-23.0.2.Final\standalone\deployments' folder?

[image: jboss runtime 1]

[image: jboss runtime 2]

[image: eclipse server tab]

[image: eclipse wildfly setting]